# Use stack2rss to receive responses via RSS

Tags: support, rss

I'm trying to setup http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/ to receive full-body "responses" (comments, edits, answers and so on) **to my own** stackoverflow questions via RSS, but I can't find the right method.

I already tried http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1204976/responses?body=true but clearly it doesn't work, since there is ( https://api.stackexchange.com/docs ) no "responses" method for "users".

http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1204976/questions/responses?body=true doesn't work either (and I truly don't like the error-proness of the guessing approach).

Stack2RSS works as expected: http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1204976/questions displays my own questions, so it's just a matter of using it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to setup http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/ to receive full-body "responses" (comments, edits, answers and so on) to my own stackoverflow questions via RSS, but I can't find the right method.

Unfortunately there is no method that allows Stack2RSS to fetch questions, comments, *and* answers for your posts.

> ... clearly it doesn't work, since there is ( https://api.stackexchange.com/docs ) no "responses" method for "users".

Unfortunately Stack2RSS has not yet been updated for v2.0 of the API - only v1.1 and v1.0 are currently supported. The legacy documentation for v1.1 is [here](http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/usage).

---

You *can* however get a feed containing all *comments* to your posts by using the [`/users/{id}/mentioned`](http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-mentioned) route. The feed will then look like this:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1204976/mentioned

Comment: View this [meta](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/760/why-cant-i-get-the-rss-feeds-of-bicycles-stackexchange-com-using-stack2rss) question